# Why does \textit not produce the expected result when used with \usebox?

Tags: boxes

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\newsavebox\temp
\newenvironment{definition}
{\begin{lrbox}{\temp}}
{\end{lrbox}\textit{\usebox\temp}}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Hello World!
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

produces a normal typeface as follows,

[image]

Why `\textit` does not produce the expected result when it works with `\usebox`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the `\usebox` is a fixed entity, locked in concrete.  It can be scaled, but its contents cannot be changed (other than by redefining it from scratch).  The way you have it setup, the `\textit` tries to work on the already complete box.  The `\textit` needs to go inside the box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\temp
\newenvironment{definition}
{\begin{lrbox}{\temp}\begin{itshape}}
{\end{itshape}\end{lrbox}{\usebox\temp}}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Hello World!
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any macro to remove the "shield" made by `\usebox`?

Comment: @GarbageCollector No: a box contains typeset material, that's the entire point. If you want to collect the content of an environment and typeset it at the end, look at the `environ` package.